# unknown type name ‘gpgme_decrypt_result_t’ when trying to compile balsa

Tags: c, ubuntu, compilation, makefile

I've been trying to compile [balsa](http://balsa.gnome.org/git-help.html) the email reader on ubuntu (i'm new to the whole process of compiling an open source project directly from sources.

so i did the whole `configure` and `make` but then I ran into this problem:

```
error: unknown type name 'gpgme_decrypt_result_t
```

after doing a little research on the error code.. it turns out that it belongs to [gpgme](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/doc/gpgme/Getting-Started.html#Getting-Started) a scary looking encryption library..

what do I do in this case? i hope i'm not expected to go in the code and debug stuff am i?

**update:**

this question is related to this other question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/255984/how-to-install-gnome-keyring-and-gmime) on the ubuntu forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you may be required to delve into the code to figure out why something doesn't build!

In this case however the answer is probably quite simple.  The main reasons I would expect a symbol from an external library to not have been defined are:

- The library header files do not exist on your system
- You have the wrong version of the library header files on your system
- The headers exist, but the compiler is not looking in the correct place

Clearly the solutions are similar: you will need to install the correct version of gpgme's header files for this software in the right place.  Note that having the library itself installed is *not* the same as having the headers.  In Ubuntu this is evident due to the presence of `-dev` packages which are the package's header files, and if you look through the repose you will find `libgpgme11-dev`.  I suggest you start by installing this, which will eliminate point 1 above.  If it still doesn't work, you'll need to start investigating the other two possibilities.

Comment: oright what you are saying reminds of when i add a library in an xcode project.. i have to be able to find the header paths for that library.. do you have a tutorial you can recommend for the equivalent in doing command line compiling if that's what it's called?

Comment: You will need to find tutorials for GNU Make and gcc/g++ (for C or C++ respectively).  If the suggestion I gave didn't help then I'm afraid you'll really need to understand what is going on.